# htaccess redirect subdomain to directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I need help to write proper rewrite rules in my htaccess files.

I need to redirect something like `fr.example.com` to `example.com/fr`, because we recently changed the whole website and the multilingual system is managed differently. The structure and the pages too.

I managed to do that successfully with this piece of code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fr\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

My problem now is to write something more specific for pages, for example :

`fr.example.com/discover/foo` should go to `example.com/fr/bar/foo` (different path, nothing consistant)

BUT ! `example.com/discover/foo` should go to `example.com/bar/foo` (end of the url is the same in both english and french)

Right now, since I have some common 301 redirects, the french urls aren't redirect properly and lead to the english pages. For example that one :

```
Redirect 301 /discover/foo /bar/otherfoo
```

Successfully redirects `example.com/discover/foo` to `example.com/bar/otherfoo` but also redirects `fr.example.com/discover/otherfoo`

How can I write two different rules for english and french? I'll have to write a bunch of different rules since everything is very different from the old subdomain to the new directory, I don't mind.

Thanks !

## EDIT

Please note that it's for a wordpress installation, and the htaccess starts with :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fr\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

should look like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?fr\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In order to capture bot www & non-www requests for subdomain.

Also this rule :

```
Redirect 301 /discover/foo /bar/foo
```

Will capture both requests to domain and sub-domains and using `mod_rewrite` here is correct not `mod_alias` so , replace this line with :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^discover/foo http://example.com/bar/foo [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(fr)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^discover/foo http://example.com/%2/bar/foo [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test.

Comment: Thank you !  But regarding the two last lines, that would redirects anything after discover/ to bar/ right? How can I be more specific? I'm updating my example because sometimes, the slug might be different (and not stay "foo")

Comment: @CécileHabran i was thinking that you want to replace any discover with bar , test it now

Comment: Mh, that works for the english (without the subdomain) but not with fr. I removed all the 301 redirects from the htaccess, but it just display the 404. The first redirect

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?fr\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/fr/$1 [L,R=301]`

works tho

Comment: I cleared it already but I did it again and tested in another browser. 
The `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(fr)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^discover/foo http://example.com/%2/bar/foo [L,R=301]` doesn't do anything :/

Comment: I edited the question since it might be usefull it's a wordpress installation

Comment: @CécileHabran it should work with sub domain ,put these rules first before any rules and test them

Comment: Thanks, it was the order of the directives. Works perfectly!